# Google search console API - UrlCrawlErrorCountsPerType

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I am not getting the result with Google search console API. while calling the function its giving 
        Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message '(query) missing required param: 'siteUrl' siteUrl/test-aap/src/Google/Service/Resource.php:165

```
 $timestamp = strtotime( '1 month ago' );
            $query = new Google_Service_Webmasters_UrlCrawlErrorCountsPerType();
            $query->setCategory("authPermissions");    
            $filter = new Google_Service_Webmasters_UrlCrawlErrorCount();
            $filter->setCount('5');
            $filter->setTimestamp($timestamp);

            $check = $query->setEntries(array($filter));
            $query->setPlatform("web");
            $getSearchresponseOb    = $service->urlcrawlerrorscounts->query('siteurl','soft404','true','web');
            $getSearchresponse      = $getSearchresponseOb->toSimpleObject();
            print_r($getSearchresponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message it's obvious.
According to Google's documentation https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/urlcrawlerrorscounts/query the "siteURL" should be a URL (eg.http://www.example.com/) therefore you should have something like this:

```
$check = $query->setEntries(array($filter));
$query->setPlatform("web");
$getSearchresponseOb = $service->urlcrawlerrorscounts->query('**http://www.example.com**','soft404','true','web');
$getSearchresponse = $getSearchresponseOb->toSimpleObject();
print_r($getSearchresponse);
```